# pass Windows user name to website

Tags: c#, iis-7, windows-authentication, application-pool

I have a .NET site which evaluates a users domain account and grabs some details from Active Directory.
This is fine when running locally via Visual Studio, but when deployed, with Windows authentication enabled (no other authentication type enabled) I can only seem to get the name of the user which the app pool is running under.
Is there a specific way to get the actual logged in user rather than the app pool user?
Currently getting the username like this:

```
string _user = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Remove(0, 8);
```

Have also tried

```
Page.User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: Is the server where it's deployed part of the domain?

Comment: application has Windows Authentication configured and server is on the domain.

Comment: @DarkW1nter, can you show the line of code that you are using to get the user..? also does your page have any login screens at all..?

Comment: Have it working with this (removes domain from user name first)    string _user = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Remove(0, 8);
Also tried Page.User.Identity.Name;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some times you need to try a few of the different ways to retrieve Active Directory info. Here are few of the ways that show up in other posts:

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
string userName = Environment.UserName;
string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity
```

Just add these, debug through and see if they are returning the iis username as well.

There are two different windows user here - first one is your application user and second is user (or windows account) under which your ASP.NET application (application pool from IIS perspective) is running. WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent will typically return this reference.

To getting actual windows user that using the application, you must enforce authentication. To do that, you can enable integrated authentication (windows authentication) in IIS for the said web site. Also modify your ASP.NET configuration to use windows authentication. Now you can use HttpContext.Current.User.Identity to get the actual user.

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

Comment: Have it configured as you say, used HttpContext but still getting the app pool user when browsing from the server, but can't authenticate when browsing remotely so I suspect it's a permissions thing I need to get the server guys to look at.  Thanks

Comment: You could try to disable Anonymous Authentication. See above

Comment: I only have Windows Authentication enabled, with allow all users.  When browsing the credentials dialog box appears which shouldn't as my user has rights to the server.

Comment: You should add the disable "?" part to see if authentication is not being forced for some reason. There are quite a few other posts with the same issue.

Comment: Ok, going to accept you answer as you've given me a lot to go on - thanks again